# Incorrect values assigned to array from text file

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new here so I apologize if I've done anything wrong in asking this question. I'm in C and I'm trying to add one to the value of an element in an array every time the element's number is read from the file. I have it set to terminate when it reads the number 30. I believe I am making out of bounds errors or something along those lines because the values printed out after I try the following code are insane.

```
int main(){

  int votes[20];
  FILE *input;

  input = fopen("votes.txt", "r");
  int currentVote;   
  while(currentVote != 30){
    fscanf(input, " ");
    fscanf(input, "%d",&currentVote);
    if(currentVote == 30){
      break;
    }
    votes[currentVote] += 1;
  }  
  fclose(input);
  int i;
  int l = 19; 
  int x;
  for(i = 0; i <= l; i++){
    x = i;
    printf("%d is %d\n",i,votes[x]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is the output that I get.

```
0 is 1
1 is 1
2 is 1
3 is 1
4 is 1835627637
5 is 1600061542
6 is 1869833335
7 is 1952802656
8 is 1
9 is 1
10 is 1
11 is 1
12 is 2
13 is 1
14 is 4196110
15 is 1
16 is 1
17 is 1
18 is 1
19 is 1
```

This is the input text file:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 30
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `vote` array is not initialized to `0` so some of the values are garbage values hence the unexpected values.

```
int votes[20] = {0};
```

Comment: It's a mistake everyone has made at least once.